# Good Practice on adding space between HTML /ASP.NET Control

Tags: asp.net, html, controls

I am now looking for any way on how to add space between controls in ASP.NET or HTML. Currently i am using A lot of **&nbsp** on my form just to add space between my controls.

For example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textbo1" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
        &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
</td>

<td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is there good practice for this or other way to do it.

Thanks in Regards

Comment: ..Correct.. i'm still a newbie :D ...so i really need to use CSS for this...i need to learn a lot of things by the way.. :D one day or sooner i will be like you guys.. :D

Comment: I totally understand, just curious as to how a newbie even new how to use `&nbsp;` for this purpose. Have never come across the non breaking space character outside of HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why dont you make use of CssStyle property called `"Paddding"` that will help you

for you case make use of `padding-right`

```
padding-right:10px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the posts i solve my problem:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textbo1" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>

  <td style="padding-left:110px;"> </td>

<td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks again

Comment: I think its better to accept answer which give you info about solution rather than pasing your solution based on given answer and accept it..also upvote the answer which provide you info...

Answer (score 1):

Use *CSS* style attribues - `padding` and `margin`.

```
.foo
{
  padding:10px 3px 4px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do using set an class on TD

for ex.

```
    <style type="text/css">
.padl{padding-left:10px}
        </style>

<table>
<tr>
<td class="padl">
        <asp:TextBox ID="textbo1" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>

<td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to introduce a stylesheet like below adn tweek the 30px values to your satisfaction. The stylesheet is best put in a file of its own but may be in lined in your html as below.

```
<style type="text/css">
   input.withSpace
   {
       margin-right: 30px;
       margin-bottom: 30px;
   }

</style>

<table>
<tr>
<td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textbo1" cssclass="withSpace" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
</td>

<td>
         <asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use style inside asp tag and format as you need

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="textbo1" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px"style="position:absolute;left:300px" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="textbox2" runat="server" Visible="true" Width="50px" ></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```